# recycling views in scroll view

Tags: android, view, scrollview, adapter

I have an app that show the tv guide for a list of channels. My UI is made from a a lot of custom views with different widths that show the tv programs, all these custom views are added into a horizontal scrollview that is added into a scrollview so my views can be scroll in 2 dimensions left-right and top-down. It all works good until i add add a lot of views and it starts to slow down very much. So i need a way to recycle views like listiew does in a scrollview maybe there is a custom made scrollview that does this, or someone has an idea how to do this, its strange that scrollview isnt backed up by an adapter like gridview and listview.

[image: This is how my UI looks]

Comment: It's not strange at all. `ScrollView`s scroll... why should they be backed by an adapter? If you want a view that works with an `Adapter`, then you should look at `AdapterView` and its subclasses. In fact, from the sound of it you probably need to create your own custom `AdapterView`.

Comment: Creating a custom AdapterView sounds like an overhead, maybe there is a more simple solution

Comment: I did something like this very recently and, like you say, performance is awful. It occurred to me once I had completed the project that I could have got the same result with a `WebView` displaying a local HTML file. This may not be sophisticated enough for your app if you want each programme to be tappable but I thought I'd mention it anyway. By the way, I should say that I never implemented this approach and so it is untested.

Comment: Can you explain me the view that is added in scrollview

Comment: Seems to me that you could use a ListView instead, and each item in the ListView could be a line in your guide. It won't be easy to recycle these though, but probably worth doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something similar only my Views were not connected as yours but they were all different sizes.

First you need to define if your entire area (not just viewing screen) has definitive or dynamical number of your custom views.

If you have definitive number of views and their positions you should create their position map with list of Rect's (Rect has a good function whether the xy point belongs). Then you define maximum of Views which are visible on your screen. For this to work without constant loading you should have maximum visible views + at least one line of border views of total objects. After all this you should easily have your own positioning system where you load views which are in bounds of your screen + some overhead (purpose of this is that you want your users to have smooth transition while scrolling at least for some length), if you need to load some in same time you unload (read reuse/ do not dispose objects and create them onScroll events) and place them according to your needs.

And if you want to determine which views should be visible you just go through list and ask whether Views Rect intersects with your Rect of area to be loaded.

Hope this image helps a little bit more

[image: Example]

I know it sounds a little bit confusing and difficult to implement but you did not asked a simple question :)
Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Awesome answer. Did you by any chance implement this if you can share code?

Comment: Problem with already used code is the fact that it is going to confuse you and most probably lead you away from solution. Feel free to send me message on my email if you have any specific question. This is a logical problem not code based.

Comment: @MarkoLazić How you address scrolling position when removing views on the left?

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView that is backed up by an adapter and recycles views is a ListView, with a couple of extra optional features on top.

Maybe you want a HorizontalScrollView that is backed by an adapter? Searching for HorizontalListView will give you a few results, ex: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android.

Comment: I cant use a listview in my situation and i tried horizontalListView the problem is that i need multiple rows so i used multiple horizontalListViews but then i need them all to scroll at the same time when 1 row is scrolled, i changed the HorizontalListView class so it will send the scroll events with distance to the remaining listviews but they lag behind the first listview that is scrolled

Comment: Why can't you use a ListView? A ListView which consumes all touch events and scrolls its children would work. Just need to repopulate and reset the scroll position the HorizontalScrollViews for each row when they get recycled and

Comment: it works, but its very slow, and the remaining rows lag behind the first row that is scrolled, and 2nd i have 20 horizontal rows, 20 HorizontalListViews will slow down any phone much more than the scrollview i have now

Comment: 6-10 on screen depending on screen size, 20 in total

Comment: Your performance issues come from having all 20 rows and all columns in the view hierarchy at once, with a correct implementation of ListView and HorizontalListView, you'll only have 6-10 rows and x-y columns loaded at once. Granted this might still be slow if each cell is itself a complex layout, but you should be able to optimise that

Comment: the only big problem with this is that i cant scroll the remaining rows with the same speed as the row that is touched, it is needed that all of the cells move to the right or left at once and it is not possible with many horizontal listviews.

Comment: Make the ListView intercept all the touches and calculate the amount to scroll X, scroll each HLV by the same amount and store the total amount of X scrolled, when a HLV is recycled by the LV, reset scrolled X by the stored amount. If the HLV are all the same width, they shouldn't get out of sync